# Should I leave outlet covers on or off for electrical inspector?

Tags: electrical, wiring, inspection

I've got an electrical inspection scheduled for 4 circuits I added to my garage. I did the work myself and my city uses the most current NEC. All wiring is running in open stud walls in my garage.

I scheduled the inspection shortly after energizing and testing all of the circuits, and it is going to be a few days before the inspection. I'm going to be using the circuits before he arrives, and I would prefer to attach the outlet covers.

Do I have to remove the outlet covers before the inspector arrives?

Comment: I think it would be better to call you local inspection department and ask the question.

Comment: Why did you schedule an inspection?

Comment: Local rules say you have to request an inspection within a day of energising, but it can be awhile before they get to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In many jurisdictions, there is a separate rough-in inspection and then a final inspection.

The rough-in is usually done with wiring in place and before drywall is installed, unless the new cabling has been snaked into place.  Wires are exposed in boxes and no devices are installed in the boxes.

The final inspection is usually done with all devices and fixtures in place, and covers on.

But local practice varies, so your best bet is to ask the building department. They are usually happy to advise, assuming your locale allows DIY.

Comment: Talked to inspector, since its an unfinished garage, both the rough/cover inspection and the final inspection can be rolled into one, so the covers are fine.